# vite & react import all images from public folder or maintain pathnames

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, import, vite

I'm creating a carousel grid of images. Each grid in the carousel has a different layout.

For example,
carousel item 1 is:

```
{`
  'area1 area1 area2 area2 area3'
  'area1 area1 area4 area5 area6'
 `}
```

and carousel item 2 is:

```
{`
  'area1 area1 area2 area3 area3'
  'area1 area1 area4 area5 area5'
 `}
```

To place the images in the correct location I've added the desired grid area to each image, like so: `".../imagename!area1.jpg"`.
This way I split the string to get the path of the image and the grid area I wish to place it in. This works great locally but the filenames change when building.

This is how I load the images:

```
const modules = import.meta.glob(
    "src/assets/images/*.jpg" //this is just a demo path
);

const imagePaths = [];

for (const path in modules) {
    modules[path]().then(() => {
        const p = new URL(path, import.meta.url);
        const data = {
            url: p.pathname,
            area: p.pathname.split("!")[1].split(".")[0],
        };
        imagePaths.push(data);
    });
}
```

How can I load and place my images?
If there's any other better methods of importing and placing I welcome them.

When I put everything into the public folder with the necessary path, the import doesn't load anything.